# Is it possible to develop Kinect (v2) application FOR windows 10? or even UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-10, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm developing a kinect application for windows 8.1 on vs2013 on windows 8.1.

I am currently using microsoft kinect v2 for windows SDK.

I want to know whether or not it can be "ported" to windows 10 platform or even xbox.

As I read [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561) the SDK support embedded win 8, win8, and win8.1.

I'm not sure whether this information is well updated or not.

I will be really grateful if someone could give me a confirmation about that information.

Answer (score 0):

Kinect is available in Nuget for 2015 or the SDK should be fine in 2013 and works for windows 10 and is definitely available for xbox. What you've done for 8.1 should work on a windows 10 desktop without rebuilding.

Comment: "..works for windows 10 and is definitely available for xbox.." did you mean UWP?

Comment: By desktop I meant classic. If you want to develop for other platforms, check out this: http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/01/17/developing-kinect-for-windows-v2-0-app-with-visual-studio-2015-on-windows-10/